# og:image doesn't work with Facebook

Tags: facebook

Im including the open graph tag for a special Facebook image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.spaghetti-factory.ch/images/logo_sf_rosenhof_fb.jpg" />
```

But if you click the share-Link

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.spaghetti-factory.ch" target="_blank" title="share on Facebook">..</a>
```

it still shows the wrong image (it should show only the fox).
See on the Website http://www.spaghetti-factory.ch

Whats wrong? Thanks for help

regards
thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to see what is wrong. But by just having a look at it, I can tell that you needed to *Fetch new scrape information* for your URL, which I did for you.

Beside that, your current image set as og is too small, therefore another picture is being fetched by Facebook. Have a look at *og:image could not be downloaded or is too small* and please note that:

> use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook

.

Comment: thanks, now it shows another image if i share it. On the fb debugger, the go:image is shown but not as the sharing-image. can i change that somewhere?

Comment: @StillerEugen, got it mate. Editted, please have a look.

Comment: thanks for help, do you see - if you share  this pic: http://www.spaghetti-factory.ch/images/logo_sf_rosenhof_fb.jpg  I only see this pic: http://www.spaghetti-factory.ch/images/logo_sf_rosenhof_fb.jpg

Comment: yes that's because http://www.spaghetti-factory.ch/images/logo_sf_rosenhof_fb.jpg is clearly smaller than 200x200px (minimum size for og:image) as I mentioned. Try to get a bigger picture for it.

Comment: Sorry! i made it smaller 220x220 an just a normal jpg but it doesn't appears - do you see it?

Comment: So every time you make a change, you should _Fetch new scrape information_ so it gets updated. I just did and it seems like it works fine with your new image.